# how to run a flask app on apache2 (digital ocean)

Tags: python, flask, apache2

I am trying to run my flask application on a digital ocean server with apache2. I follow this tutorial

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps

following this tutorial works fine for me. However, I was wondering how to get an app running if the run.app() command is given in run.py instead of **init**.py? So how do I have to change

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/FlaskApp.conf
```

and

```
/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
```

The setup in the tutorial always seems to look for

```
/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/__init__.py
```

My run.py looks like this

```
#!/opt/local/bin/python
from flask import Flask
from app import app
#app.run(debug = True)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
```

thanks carl

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: well isn't this the usual setup for such an application? I tried to merge run.py into __init__.py, but that causes some trouble in my views.py... I thought there should be a way to directly use run.py?

Comment: I have an application running currently that has everything in the init.py

Comment: yes I got it working with init.py as well, but there must be a way to tell apache noy to call __init__.py but run.py?

Comment: Go down to the troubleshooting section of this article, it may help.  http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/

Comment: I found that site already... doesn't seem to address my issue

Comment: Does it just not work if you move the `app.run()` from _init.py_ to run.py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wgsi server (modwsgi in your case) is looking for a wgsi-compatible python object that it can use.  Your `run.py` file is grabbing that Flask `app` object, which meets those requirements.

So in theory, all you need to do is to change your `flask.wsgi` file contents from (as the tutorial you linked states):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/")

from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'Add your secret key'
```

to:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/")

from run import app as application
application.secret_key = 'Add your secret key'
```

Comment: thanks Doobeh... I actually changed from apache to nginx and that worked fine for me... but good to know for the next time

Comment: The same is true of uWSGI or Gunicorn-- the web-server (Apache, Nginx) doesn't really matter, it's the wsgi server that interacts with the Flask application.  nginx with gunicorn, in my opinion is the easiest deployment for most people, so I'm glad you've moved in that direction.